Why was temperature difference not historically be considered a form of energy
Heat energy $Q$ cannot be measured directly, but the temperature difference can be measured with a thermometer, and only a subtraction is needed.
When studying nonequilibrium processes, treating temperature difference as some kind of potential energy may simplify heat transfer equations and models and provide a more intuitive description. This helps to understand and predict the behavior of heat flow.
Treating temperature difference as energy can optimize the design of heat engines, promoting the development of heat engines and heat exchangers.
So, why was temperature difference not historically be considered a form of energy? Why people prefer the idea of some kind of fluids being the energy? At the same time, electric current is not considered as energy itself.

In short: Energy as we know it was understood much more recently than temperature. The idea of heat as energy exchange was understood almost immediately with the understanding of energy.
For pre-history of the concept check: When did the concept of temperature first arise?
The first insight on the idea that hotness-coldness could be observed came from the end of the 16th century with scientists like Galileo, who were able to make thermoscopes that reacted when heated but had no scale. Later, other scientists like Robert Fludd, Santorio or Ferdinand II started putting a scale producing a thermometer. In the same century, temperature became an important variable to measure in experiments. In 1714 Daniel Farenheit came up with a more modern scale (Farenheit scale).
As for energy, this concept is much more recent. Ideas of a vis viva started with Leibniz in 1690s, Émilie du Chatêlet might be credited with an early form of the conservation of mechanical energy in 18th century, but the real thermodynamics and understanding of energy came up in the 19th century with Carnot, Rankine, Kelvin, Joule, von Mayer and so on.
Not only energy was understood much later, but it was its understanding that ended the thermal "fluids" that you mentioned. Around the beginning of the 18th century, Stahl came up with the phlogiston, an imponderable fluid that appeared in reactions taking some of the mass and either heated or cooled a sample. Phlogiston theory died with Antoine Lavoisier who showed the conservation of mass in 1783. However, people like Lavoisier and others quickly suggested that there could still be some other caloric fluid that was related to the hot-cold exchanges.
That's when Joule and von Mayer come up. In the 1840s, the two independently showed that mechanical work could produce temperature changes and viceversa temperature differences could produce mechanical motion. This discovery led very quickly to the development of energy relations and thermodynamics.
Note that however the idea that temperature difference can lead to motion precedes our understanding of it as an energy. The Watt's steam engine is from 1764. James Watt himself explained his ideas in terms of phlogiston. Watt even debated with Lavoisier about phlogiston [J. Watt, Phil Trans p.333 (26th April 1783) ].

Thank you, I have always had a vague feeling that thermodynamics and the steam engine were invented at about the same time, even though I know the actual year.

@Americanboy you are welcome, if this solves your doubts you can validate this answer by clicking in the checkmark on the left.

I'm sorry, I would like to see different answers from different people，so I can compare and choose which one I want to approve.

@Americanboy is there something else that you want to know?

I just think that modern thermodynamics still believes that something is flowing, and they call the flowing thing heat. Is this because of inheritance?Why do physicists like this concept? Without it, we would still have all the technology we have today.

@Americanboy it depends, in thermal transport what truly flows is the "heat flow" field vector
